# MIPS : Storing integers or integer arrays as local variables

Tags: assembly, mips

In a problem, I have been asked to use the concept of assigning integer variables as local variables in MIPS assembly language.
which is. Write a program which
(i) reads an integer in a local variable "inp" (with proper prompt)

What actually is meant by this assigning integer variables as local variables? and how do i go about this problem?

Comment: Just allocate some space on stack for the local variable, then you can read number, write to memory as per normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the following [tutorial](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm).  Part of this exercise is just invoking the right system routine:

> The read_int, read_float and read_double services read an entire line
>   of input up to and including the newline character.

As far as your question goes, it just means read the value the user enters into a variable (perhaps a register or a temp variable in your case).

**Read integer value, store in RAM location with label int_value (presumably declared in data section)**

```
    li  $v0, 5            # load appropriate system call code into register $v0;
                          # code for reading integer is 5
    syscall               # call operating system to perform operation
    sw  $v0, int_value    # value read from keyboard returned in register $v0;
                          # store this in desired location
```

Comment: Then why does it say "local variables" ?

Comment: A temporary variable or register is a local variable.